# can't add email address to a contact from the People in Office 365 after creating a contact with only a name using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365-apps, azure-ad-graph-api

After creating a contact with only a contact name with my app using Microsoft Graph; I added an email address to this contact in People UI in Office 365 (Business Premium), and I can't save this change.

I get the following message:

> The contact can't be updated right now. Please try again later.

I am able to modify other fields, but not the email field in People.